# VBA Sum active cell to top

Tags: vba, excel, sum

Ive been trying to write a macro (I appreciate this can be done without VBA, but its part of a larger macro, so would much rather it were done in VBA), which essentially has a list of contract names in column C, and a list of number of contracts in column E. All the contract names are grouped (i.e. Apples would all be with Apples), basically I want the VBA to net off positives and negatives for each contract, and remove anything else, starting with higher row numbers and working up (either by deleting the row or changing the value in column E to 0, or alternatively lowering it) so the cumulative for each contract becomes 0

ie

```
-5
-7
3
8
4
```

would change the 4 at the end to a 1

As all the contracts are grouped, once its done this for the top contract, for the subsequent contracts I just need to check the sum from the active cell to the top is 0 rather than specifically for that contract

In the situation where where all quantities were positive, or all quantities were negative, it would remove all of them

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

Does this get you started?
I was working with a range of random numbers starting at A1 down to A5 my sample number set was; -5,-7,3,8,4  The result changed the last cell to "1"

```
Sub net_fix()
Dim top As Integer
Dim bottom As Long
Dim running_t As Integer
Dim eval As Long
Dim net As Long
Dim rng As Range


running_t = 0
net = 0
top = 1
bottom = Worksheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'last row with data (change to fit your application)
Set rng = Worksheets(1).Range(Cells(top, 1), Cells(bottom, 1))

'check for all negative or positive numbers
eval = 0
For Each cell In rng
    If cell.Value < 0 Then eval = eval + 1
Next

If eval = bottom + 1 - top Then 'all cells were negative so change value to 0
    With rng
        .Value = 0
    End With
End If

eval = 0
For Each cell In rng
    If cell.Value > 0 Then eval = eval + 1
Next

If eval = bottom + 1 - top Then 'all cells were positive
    With rng
        .Value = 0
    End With
End If

net = WorksheetFunction.Sum(rng)
For i = bottom To top Step -1   'fix the cells from bottom to top until the net = 0
    If Not net = 0 Then
        last_t = Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 1)
            If net > last_t Then Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 1) = 0: net = WorksheetFunction.Sum(rng)
            If net < last_t Then Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 1) = last_t - net: net = WorksheetFunction.Sum(rng)
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thats awesome thanks, the only trouble I have with it, is it shouldnt be able to make the absolute value of any number in the data larger, and on the data Ive tested it on, in the situation where the total sum is negative, but the last cell has a positive value in it, rather than making that final positive value larger, I want it to go and make the final negative value smaller, or to zero if necessary, and so on if the sum is still negative... Is that possible? Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Alex, anything is possible. Ill look at it again later and see what I can come up with, honestlymy ssolution is probably not the best one, and there are always many ways to solve problems. Can you post a few data sets and show us exactly what you would like it to do? When I brainstorm code it helps me to write it down as if I were explaining it to a child, ignoring the finer details but spending as much time possible explaining what should happen in every distinct step. That would help me in discerning exactly what you are after.  Matt

Comment: thank you so much for your help.  So for example 3, -2, 7, 4 it would change the 4 to a 0, the 7 to a 0 and the 3 to a 2. What I'm trying to get at is the absolute value of each number shouldn't increase, and after a number is changed to 0, if the sum still isn't 0 it does the same to the next  number that makes the sum not 0. Another example, 6, 4, 8 it would change all 3 numbers to 0. Another, -4, -3, -2, 5 here it would change the -2 to 0, and the -3 to -1. I hope this makes it clearer! Thank you again